# How to do client on-prem deployment of machine learning models without exposing the code files and model?

Tags: docker, azure-devops, gcp

I am working on a project that involves the deployment of my code and ML model files to be deployed on a client virtual machine.

Since this is a proprietary code and model, is there a way to deploy this code on the VM possibly in a docker without exposing my code and model files?